# ember mirage get data from other file than config.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

in config.js i have:

```
this.get('/tests', function() {
  return {

 //data here

 }
```

How can I get data from other file in mirage instead of config.js? For example from mirage/abc/tests.js
Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could statically import another file at the top of this file, and then return it. But Mirage is designed to work with a `db` object which you get as a parameter to this function:

```
this.get('/tests', function(db) {
  return db.users;
});
```

You can seed the fake `db` object with data by putting a file under `/mirage/fixtures`. This is good because it lets you change the data this route responds to, for example during development or during testing.

It may be helpful to read over Mirage's guide on [seeding your database](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/seeding-your-database/).